# Sorting a collection of objects (not an array)

Tags: javascript, sorting

Is it possible to sort a collection of objects (not an array)? I’m looking at something like this:

```
{
  "dbcc0a7c-f0af-4253-9aa2-d70e65e68cca": {
    "mttd": -86444,
    "mtta": 0,
    "mttm": null,
    "mttr": null,
    "count": 1,
    "total_time": 1548933
  },
  "efc8611e-7b92-4885-b160-c69c91b654b2": {
    "mttd": null,
    "mtta": null,
    "mttm": null,
    "mttr": null,
    "count": 0,
    "total_time": null
  },
  "348c352d-5d61-445c-8fb9-c7081adae641": {
    "mttd": null,
    "mtta": 0,
    "mttm": 448453,
    "mttr": null,
    "count": 1,
    "total_time": 1897322
  },
  "e4a88b56-1c58-432e-afc6-79ddc87cc7f8": {
    "mttd": null,
    "mtta": 0,
    "mttm": 92535,
    "mttr": null,
    "count": 2,
    "total_time": 3090603
  }
}
```

I need to sort by count. I tried this, but of course it doesn’t work since it’s just for arrays:

```
const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.count - a.count;
});
```

Comment: Convert your object to an array and then sort it? What's the problem?

Comment: Short answer is _no_, you cannot sort objects, only arrays.